MockStatic and MockConstruction not working in spring batch test cases
I am trying to mock static function and new instantiations in the spring tasklet step testing, but the mocks are not working and are going to the actual implementations.
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(BatchConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BatchConfig.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class, DatabaseConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestPropertySource(value = { "classpath:application-test.properties" })

public class TestingProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;
    @InjectMocks
    Processor processor;
    @InjectMocks
    Payload payload;

    @MockBean
    JobListner jobListner;
    @MockBean
    AlertNotification ans;
    @MockBean
    AlertConfig alertConfig;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pipeline")
    Job job;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("JobLauncher")
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @AfterEach
    public void cleanUp() {
        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    public StepExecution getExecutionContext() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().put(SchedulerConstants.CONTEXT, context);
        return execution;
    }
    @Test
    public void testingProcessorTasklet() throws Exception {
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(SchedulerConstants.TENANTID_CONTEXT, "TestTenantId")
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        StepExecution executionContext = getExecutionContext();

        when(mockedClass1.getTenant(anyString())).thenReturn("mockedClass2");
        when(mockedClass2.getTenantId()).thenReturn("mockTenantId");
//these are working they return the mocked values


        try (MockedStatic<ConnectionFactory> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ConnectionFactory.class)) {
            Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
            mockedStatic.when(() -> ConnectionFactory.getConnection(any())).thenReturn(connection);
//these are not working even MockConstruction is not mocking

            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("PROCESS_IT", jobParameters, executionContext
                    .getExecutionContext());

            Assertions.assertEquals(BatchStatus.STARTING, jobExecution.getStatus());
            while (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
            }
            Assertions.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        }
    }
}

Having issue with this call, is there any other way of mocking or is there some issue with the way I have done.
conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection(tenantID);

This is the line I want to mock the implementation for, using spring batch 5 and mockito 5.
My guess its because of the annotations as in my other files mock static is working fine, where the spring batch annotations are not present.
How can I mock these calls, as I do not want to execute the actual implementations of these classes?

You're mixing Sping Boot Test annotations like MockBean with Mockito like InjectMocks. I haven't analyzed your example, but it is most likely the problems in your test.

+1 to not mixing test annotations. Moreover, any reason not using an embedded db for tests? It would be easier than mocking the connection factory, the connection, and other calls up to the datasource set on the job repository.

I have removed the @InjectMocks, if I dont use the @MockBean annotations the class dependancies are failing(No qualifying bean of type 'abc.class'), even without the injectbeans the mockStatic is not working.
As for the connection factory it was just an example we use a local db for testing, but even other static classes or MockedConstructions are not working. @lesiak
